# How to find the memory address of the same thing each time a program starts up?

Tags: memory, client, memory-address

I recently picked programming back up, and I was wondering about reading the memory of other programs.

First off, I am doing this for purely educational purposes only and just wondered if it could be done. I mean in no way to achieve some sort of advantage in any game.

Anyway, I loaded a game (Let's call it genericmmorpg), and logged in. I wanted to find the name of my character in the memory (let's say timmy).

So I loaded up Cheat Engine (The only memory analyzer that I knew to work with it) and found the address where my name was stored. However, each time the game client opens up it changes the memory address where my name is stored. Now, I know that there are many programs that automatically read the name of your character outside of the game so I know it can be done. Also, I know that there are trainers for singleplayer games that specifically target certain memory addresses.

I was just wondering if I am taking the right approach (searching through the memory) and I just need some altering to my methods, or is there some other these programs most likely get the name of a character.

Comment: In case of Cheat Engine, you should follow the tutorial that comes with the program. It explains how to find base pointers for things that change from startup to startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Most modern OS's use "virtual memory".  All the running program ever sees is a *logical* address.  If you have three processes running, each process will have their own address 0xe00ff002 (for example), and the *actual* value for each process at that address will be *different*.

This is a long way of saying that, in a virtual memory OS, one process cannot read another process's memory.

2) Yes, you can certainly search for text strings.  Either in the memory of a process.  Or in the binary .exe file that the process is running.

3) It depends on the program, on the OS, whether each process will load exactly the same, using exactly the same memory addresses, each time it loads.

In most programs running on most OS's, the answer is "No: different things will generally load in different locations at different times."